# ¿Cómo hacer comparaciones correctamente con javascript?

Tags: javascript

quiero hacer una comparacion con estos dos elementos metiendolos en un if
para imprimir alertas pero no obtengo lo esperado al hacerlo

```
  <!-- 

/**********************AAAAAA UU  UU TTTTTT OOOOOO RRRRRR EEEEEE SSSSSS
/**********************AAAAAA UU  UU   TT   OO  OO RRR  R EE     SS
/**********************AA  AA UU  UU   TT   OO  OO RRRRRR EEEE   SSSSSS
/**********************AAAAAA UU  UU   TT   OO  OO RR  RR EEEE   SSSSSS
/**********************AA  AA UUUUUU   TT   OO  OO RR  RR EE         SS
/**********************AA  AA UUUUUU   TT   OOOOOO RR  RR EEEEEE SSSSSS


Juan Ortiz juanjoseortizalbornoz@gmail.com   Venezuela
Hanyerck Diaz    Hanyerck@hotmail.com       República Dominicana 
Gracias por su visita                     
-->


<?php
require_once('bdd.php');
require ("PHPMailer/class.phpmailer.php");

$sql = "SELECT * FROM events ORDER BY color";
$ip= $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$req = $bdd->prepare($sql);
$req->execute();

$events = $req->fetchAll();

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link href="css/starter-template.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/estilos.css" rel="stylesheet"> 
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/sa.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <title>Inicio</title>



    <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- FullCalendar -->
    <link href='css/fullcalendar.css' rel='stylesheet' />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <style>


td.fc-day.fc-past {
    background-color: #EEEEEE;
}

.fa-facebook, .fa-facebook-square {
    color: #3b5998
}
.fa-twitter, .fa-twitter-square {
    color: #00aced
}
.fa-google-plus, .fa-google-plus-square {
    color: #dd4b39
}
.fa-youtube, .fa-youtube-play, .fa-youtube-square {
    color: #bb0000
}
.fa-tumblr, .fa-tumblr-square {
    color: #32506d
}
.fa-vine {
    color: #00bf8f
}
.fa-flickr {
    color: #ff0084
}
.fa-vimeo-square {
    color: #aad450
}
.fa-pinterest, .fa-pinterest-square {
    color: #cb2027
}
.fa-linkedin, .fa-linkedin-square {
    color: #007bb6
}
.fa-instagram {
  #color: #517fa4;
}
.fa-spotify {
    color: #1ED760;
}


#notification-icon{

}



    body {
        padding-top: 10px;

    }
    #calendar {
        max-width: 940px;
    }
    .col-centered{
        float: none;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }




    </style>



</head>
<script>setTimeout('document.location.reload()',600000); </script>
<body style="background-repeat: no-repeat;  background-position: center; background-image: url(http://prensaalcaldiadearismendi.epizy.com/img/imagendefondo.jpg);">    >

<!-- <img src="img/png.png" class="centrar"> -->

    <!-- Navigation -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Calendario</a>
            </div>
            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                   <li>
                        <a href="#">Contacto: <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> juanjoseortizalbornoz@gmail.com / <i class="fa fa-whatsapp"></i> +58 4162910634 </a> 

                    </li>



                </ul>




            </div>
            <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.container -->
    </nav>
    <!-- Page Content -->


    <div class="container">

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
               <h1>Calendario de actividades 


                <br/>Alcaldía de Arismendi</h1> 
                <div id="calendar" class="col-centered">
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
        <!-- /.row -->
<!--notification -->





        <!-- Modal -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="ModalAdd" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
          <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document" >
            <div class="modal-content">

            <form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="addEvent.php">
            <!-- este es para agregar los eventos , mas abajo esta el de editarlos -->
              <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h3 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Nuevo evento<div align="center"><span class="fa fa-3x fa-facebook-square"></span><span class="fa fa-3x fa-twitter-square"></span><span class="fa fa-3x fa-google-plus-square"></span><span class="fa fa-3x fa-youtube-square"></span><span class="fa fa-3x fa-tumblr-square"></span></span><span class="fa fa-3x fa-vimeo-square"></span></span><span class="fa fa-3x fa-pinterest-square"></span><span class="fa fa-3x fa-linkedin-square"></span><span class="fa fa-3x fa-instagram"></span></div></h3>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">

                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="title" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Título</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                      <input type="text" name="title" class="form-control" id="title" placeholder="Debe ser corto" required >
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="color" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Importancia</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                      <select name="color" class="form-control" id="color" required>
                                      <option value="">SELECCIONE</option>
                          <option style="color:#000;" value="#000">&#9724; SIN TRASCENDENCIA</option>
                          <option style="color:#008000;" value="#008000">&#9724; IMPORTANTE</option>
                          <option style="color:#FF0000;" value="#FF0000">&#9724; ULTIMA HORA</option>
                          <option style="color:#40E0D0;" value="#40E0D0">&#9724; EFEMERIDES</option>
                           <option style="color:#FFD700;" value="#FFD700">&#9724; OTROS</option>

                        </select>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="start" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Fecha Inicial</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                      <input type="text" name="start" class="form-control" id="start" readonly>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="end" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Fecha Final</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                      <input type="text" name="end" class="form-control" id="end" readonly>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="lugar" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Lugar</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                      <input type="text" name="lugar" class="form-control" id="lugar" placeholder="lugar del acontecimiento" required >
                    </div>
                  </div>


                 <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="motivo" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Motivo</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                      <input type="text" name="motivo" class="form-control" id="motivo" placeholder="motivo" required >
                    </div>
                  </div>

                   <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="fuente" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Fuente</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                      <input type="text" name="fuente" class="form-control" id="fuente" placeholder="fuente" required > 
                    </div>
                  </div>

              <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="hora" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Hora</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                      <input type="time" name="hora" class="form-control" id="hora" placeholder="hora del suceso" required >
                    </div>
                  </div>


               <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="fotografo" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Fotógrafo</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                      <select name="fotografo" class="form-control" id="fotografo" required>
                                      <option value="">SELECCIONE</option>
                          <option value="ANMAIRYS SALAZAR">&#9724; ANMAIRYS SALAZAR</option>
                          <option value="JOSE AGREDAS">&#9724; JOSE AGREDAS</option>
                          <option value="AMBOS">&#9724; TODO EL EQUIPO</option>


                        </select>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                 <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="descripcion" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Descripción</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
<textarea name="descripcion" class="form-control" id="descripcion" placeholder="describa el suceso con detalles" required ></textarea>
                    </div>
                  </div>


                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="tipo" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Tipo</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                      <select name="tipo" class="form-control" id="tipo" required>
                                      <option value="">SELECCIONE</option>
                          <option value="ECONOMIA">&#9724; ECONOMIA</option>
                          <option value="CULTURA">&#9724; CULTURA</option>
                          <option value="SOCIEDAD">&#9724; SOCIEDAD</option>
                          <option value="OTROS">&#9724; OTROS</option>

                        </select>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="reportero" class="col-sm-2 control-label" >Periodista</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                      <select name="reportero" class="form-control" id="reportero" required>
                                      <option value="">SELECCIONE</option>
                          <option value="EVELYN CHAVEZ">&#9724; EVELYN CHAVEZ</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="etiquetas" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Etiquetas</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                     <textarea name="etiquetas" class="form-control" id="etiquetas" placeholder="escriba y separe con espacio las etiquetas a usar" required onkeyup="mayus(this);" style="color: blue;"></textarea>
                    </div>
                  </div>




              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Guardar</button>
              </div>
            </form>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>







        <!-- Modal -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="ModalEdit" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
          <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
            <form id="hanyerck" class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="editEventTitle.php">
              <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Ver/Modificar Evento</h4>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">

                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="title" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Título</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                      <input type="text" name="title" class="form-control titulo"  placeholder="Titulo" disabled>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="color" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Importancia</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                      <select name="color" class="form-control importancia" id="color" disabled>
                          <option value="">SELECCIONAR</option>
                          <option style="color:#000;" value="#000">&#9724; SIN TRASCENDENCIA</option>
                          <option style="color:#008000;" value="#008000">&#9724; IMPORTANTE</option>
                          <option style="color:#FF0000;" value="#FF0000">&#9724; ULTIMA HORA</option>
                          <option style="color:#40E0D0;" value="#40E0D0">&#9724; EFEMERIDES</option>
                           <option style="color:#FFD700;" value="#FFD700">&#9724; OTROS</option>


                        </select>  
                    </div>
                  </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="lugar" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Lugar</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                      <input type="text" name="lugar" class="form-control lugar" id="lugar" placeholder="lugar del acontecimiento"  disabled>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                   <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="motivo" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Motivo</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                      <input type="text" name="motivo" class="form-control motivo" id="motivo" placeholder="motivo"  disabled>
                    </div>
                  </div>


                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="fuente" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Fuente</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                      <input type="text" name="fuente" class="form-control fuente" id="fuente" placeholder="fuente"  disabled>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="hora" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Hora</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                      <input type="time" name="hora" class="form-control hora" id="hora" placeholder="hora del suceso"  disabled >
                    </div>
                  </div>


                     <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="fotografo" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Fotógrafo</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                      <select name="fotografo" class="form-control fotografo" id="fotografo" disabled>
                                      <option value="">SELECCIONE</option>
                          <option value="ANMAIRYS SALAZAR">&#9724; ANMAIRYS SALAZAR</option>
                          <option value="JOSE AGREDAS">&#9724; JOSE AGREDAS</option>
                          <option value="AMBOS">&#9724; AMBOS</option>

                        </select>
                    </div>
                  </div>


                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="descripcion" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Descripción</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                      <textarea  name="descripcion" class="form-control descripcion" id="descripcion" placeholder="describa el suceso" disabled ></textarea>
                    </div>
                  </div>


                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="tipo" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Tipo</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                      <select name="tipo" class="form-control tipo" id="tipo" disabled>
                          <option value="">SELECCIONE</option>
                          <option value="ECONOMIA">&#9724; ECONOMIA</option>
                          <option value="CULTURA">&#9724; CULTURA</option>
                          <option value="SOCIEDAD">&#9724; SOCIEDAD</option>
                          <option value="OTROS">&#9724; OTROS</option>

                        </select>
                    </div>
                  </div>



                   <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="reportero" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Periodista</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                      <select name="reportero" class="form-control periodista" id="reportero" disabled>
                          <option value="">SELECCIONE</option>
                          <option value="EVELYN CHAVEZ">&#9724; EVELYN CHAVEZ</option>


                        </select>
                    </div>
                  </div>


                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="etiquetas" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Etiquetas</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                     <textarea name="etiquetas" class="form-control etiquetas" id="etiquetas" placeholder="escriba y separe con espacio las etiquetas a usar" required onkeyup="mayus(this);" style="color: blue;" disabled></textarea>
                    </div>
                  </div>





                   <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="razonmodificacion" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Razon de la modificacion</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                     <textarea name="razonmodificacion" class="form-control razonmodificacion" id="razonmodificacion" placeholder="escriba la razon de la modificacion, si aparece algo aqui fue modificado el evento"  required disabled></textarea>
                    </div>
                  </div>


                  <div class="form-group" id="razondeeliminacion" hidden="true">
                    <label for="razondeeliminacion" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Razon de la eliminacion</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                     <input name="razondeeliminacion" class="form-control razondeeliminacion" id="razondeeliminacion" placeholder="escriba la razon de la eliminacion" disabled  pattern=".{15,}"   required title="explique con mas de 15 letras por que desea la eliminar el evento"></input>
                    </div>
                  </div>





                     <div class="form-group"> 
                        <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                          <div class="checkbox">Seleccione una opcion </br>
                          <label class="text-danger"><input name="checkbox" type="checkbox" id="checkboxeditar" value="checkbox" onclick="activarcasilla(this)"> Editar Evento</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<label class="text-danger">
                          </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>





                  <input type="hidden" name="id" class="form-control" id="id">


              </div>






              <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
                <button  id="btsubmit" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" disabled>Guardar</button>
              </div>
            </form>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

    </div>
    <!-- /.container -->

    <!-- jQuery Version 1.11.1 -->
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <!-- FullCalendar -->
    <script src='js/moment.min.js'></script>
    <script src='js/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.min.js'></script>
    <script src='js/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.js'></script>
    <script src='js/fullcalendar/locale/es.js'></script>




    <script>

    $(document).ready(function() {


$('#checkboxeditar').click(function() {// este es el modal? no , esto es un checkbox que habilita/deshabilita campos 
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
       document.getElementById("razondeeliminacion").checked=false
 $('.titulo').removeAttr('disabled');
 $('.importancia').removeAttr('disabled');
 $('.lugar').removeAttr('disabled');
 $('.motivo').removeAttr('disabled');
 $('.fuente').removeAttr('disabled');
 $('.hora').removeAttr('disabled');
 $('.fotografo').removeAttr('disabled');
 $('.descripcion').removeAttr('disabled');
 $('.tipo').removeAttr('disabled');
 $('.periodista').removeAttr('disabled');
 $('.etiquetas').removeAttr('disabled');
 $('.razonmodificacion').removeAttr('disabled');
 $('#btsubmit').removeAttr('disabled');

} else {
            $('.titulo').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            $('.importancia').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            $('.lugar').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            $('.motivo').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            $('.fuente').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            $('.hora').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            $('.fotografo').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            $('.descripcion').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            $('.tipo').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            $('.periodista').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            $('.etiquetas').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            $('.razonmodificacion').attr('disabled', 'disabled');




        }
    });






       var date = new Date();
       var yyyy = date.getFullYear().toString();
       var mm = (date.getMonth()+1).toString().length == 1 ? "0"+(date.getMonth()+1).toString() : (date.getMonth()+1).toString();
       var dd  = (date.getDate()).toString().length == 1 ? "0"+(date.getDate()).toString() : (date.getDate()).toString();





        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({




            header: {
                 language: 'es',
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay',

            },
            defaultDate: yyyy+"-"+mm+"-"+dd,
            editable: true,
            eventLimit: true, 
            selectable: true,
            selectHelper: true,

            select: function(start, end) {
                //aqui es donde deseo hacer la comprobacion para mostrar //luego el modal 
                $('#ModalAdd #start').val(moment(start).format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
                $('#ModalAdd #end').val(moment(end).format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
                $('#ModalAdd').modal('show');


            },





            eventConstraint: {
                start: moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm'),
                end: '2100-01-01' 
            },
            eventRender: function(event, element) {
                element.bind('dblclick', function() {
                    $('#ModalEdit #id').val(event.id);
                    $('#ModalEdit #title').val(event.title);
                    $('#ModalEdit #color').val(event.color);
                    $('#ModalEdit').modal('show');
                    /*
                    $('[name="title"]').val(event.title);
                    $('[name="lugar"]').val(event.lugar);
                    $('[name="motivo"]').val(event.motivo);
                    $('[name="fuente"]').val(event.fuente);
                    $('[name="tipo"]').val(event.tipo);
                    $('[name="hora"]').val(event.hora);
                    $('[name="fotografo"]').val(event.fotografo);
                    $('[name="descripcion"]').val(event.descripcion);
                    $('[name="reportero"]').val(event.reportero);
                    $('[name="etiquetas"]').val(event.etiquetas);
                    */
                    var form = hanyerck || $('#hanyerck')[0];
                    var keys = Object.keys(event);
                    while(key = keys.shift()){
                        //console.log(key);
                        try{
                            var input = form.querySelector('input[name="'+key+'"],select[name="'+key+'"],textarea[name="'+key+'"]');
                            console.log(key, event[key], input);
                            if(input.nodeName == 'SELECT'){
                                var option = input.querySelector('[value="'+event[key]+'"]');
                                if(option != null){
                                    console.log('selcet====================================');
                                    //$(input).find('option').removeAttr('selected');
                                    //$(option).attr('selected','selected').click();
                                    option.setAttribute('selected','selected');

                                }
                            }else{
                                input.value = event[key];
                            }
                        }catch(e){}
                    }

                    //console.log(event);
                });
            },
            eventDrop: function(event, delta, revertFunc) { // si changement de position

                edit(event);

            },
            eventResize: function(event,dayDelta,minuteDelta,revertFunc) { // si changement de longueur

                edit(event);

            },




            events: [
            <?php foreach($events as $event): 

                $start = explode(" ", $event['start']);
                $end = explode(" ", $event['end']);
                if($start[1] == '00:00:00'){
                    $start = $start[0];
                }else{
                    $start = $event['start'];
                }
                if($end[1] == '00:00:00'){
                    $end = $end[0];
                }else{
                    $end = $event['end'];
                }
            ?>
                {
                    id: '<?php echo $event['id']; ?>',
                    title: '<?php echo $event['title']; ?>',
                    start: '<?php echo $start; ?>',
                    end: '<?php echo $end; ?>',

                    color: '<?php echo $event['color']; ?>',
                    lugar: '<?php echo $event['lugar']; ?>',
                    motivo: '<?php echo $event['motivo']; ?>',
                    fuente: '<?php echo $event['fuente']; ?>',
                    tipo: '<?php echo $event['tipo']; ?>',
                    hora: '<?php echo $event['hora']; ?>',
                    fotografo: '<?php echo $event['fotografo']; ?>',
                    descripcion: '<?php echo $event['descripcion']; ?>',
                    reportero: '<?php echo $event['reportero']; ?>',
                    etiquetas: '<?php echo $event['etiquetas']; ?>',
                    razonmodificacion: '<?php echo $event['razonmodificacion']; ?>',

                },
            <?php endforeach; ?>
            ]
        });
        //funcion para mover eventos y cambiarlos de fecha
        function edit(event){
            start = event.start.format('YYYY-MM-DD ');
            if(event.end){
                end = event.end.format('YYYY-MM-DD ');
            }else{
                end = start;
            }

            id =  event.id;

            Event = [];
            Event[0] = id;
            Event[1] = start;
            Event[2] = end;
            //console.log(event,Event);
            $.ajax({
             url: 'editEventDate.php',
             type: "POST",
             data: {Event:Event,title:event.title},
             success: function(rep) {
                    if(rep == 'OK'){




                        swal({
  position: 'top-end',
  type: 'success',
  title: 'Se ha modificado el dia del evento de forma exitosa',
  showConfirmButton: false,
  timer: 1500
});






                    }else{
                        swal({
  type: 'error',
  title: 'Algo salio mal...',
  html: '<i class="fa fa-phone"></i>  <i class="fa fa-whatsapp"></i>   04162910634  '
}); 
                    }
                }
            });
        }

    });




function mayus(texto) {
  let val = texto.value
  let result = val.split(' ').map(item => !item.startsWith('#') && item != '' ? '#' + item : item)
  texto.value = result.join(' ')
}





</script>

</body>

</html>
```

¿cómo puedo hacerla correctamente?

Comment: No se mucho de JQuery, pero tengo entendido de que si usarás múltiples selectores de ID's se deben separar por comas "$('#ModalAdd, #start')". Podrías compartir el resto de tu código?.

Comment: No está mal escrito. @BDOM el código funciona perfectamente salvo la comparación

Comment: Dónde asignas las variables start y end?

Comment: eso es lo que necesito hacer como tal
asignarle el valor de  $('#ModalAdd #start').val(moment(start).format('YYYY-MM-DD'));  a start  y  $('#ModalAdd #end').val(moment(end).format('YYYY-MM-DD')); a end para hacer la comprobación @PauloUrbanoRivera , no se hacerlo

Comment: Recomendación: el ejemplo a incluir en tu pregunta debe funcionar (debe ser completo) y eso lo cumples, pero también debe ser el mínimo viable.

Comment: trate pero necesitaban ver todo el codigo, por eso edite la pregunta y lo coloque todo @Alfabravo

Comment: Esta pregunta necesita algunas mejoras: sé más específico (¿qué condicional es el que no funciona?) e intenta limitar el código al mínimo necesario (no puede ser que para una comparación en JavaScript los usuarios que quieran ayudarte tengan que rebuscar en 700+ líneas de código). ¿Por qué dices que necesitaban ver todo el código? No necesitamos todo, sólo las partes relevantes. Lee [ask] y cómo crear un [mcve] para más información.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar la librería de *moment.js* para comparar tus fechas usando la función  [**isBefore**](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-before/)

```
$('#ModalAdd #start').val(moment(start).format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
$('#ModalAdd #end').val(moment(end).format('YYYY-MM-DD'));

var startDate = moment(start).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
var endDate = moment(end).format('YYYY-MM-DD');

//opcionalmente puedes comparar tus fechas en string directamente aquí
if(moment(startDate).isBefore(endDate)) 
{
  alert("mal ");
}
else
{
  $('#ModalAdd').modal('show');
}
```

También puedes revisar como usar las funciones *isSame* e *isAfter*. O si deseas obtener cual es la diferencia existe [**diff**](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/)

Comment: mas o menos asi lo trate de hacer yo pero en todos los cuadros donde doy click me trae el mensaje "mal" .

Comment: Habrá que ver que fechas estas comparando..

Comment: Si, por favor @JuanOrtiz agrega la parte donde declaras start y date

Comment: NO la tengo porque no se como hacer esa declaracion @LeviArista. si la supiera no estaría haciendo esa pregunta, ¿no crees?

Comment: Amigo, el colega @LeviArista te acaba de dar la respuesta de como guardar esas variables... lo que te pedimos es que especifiques las fechas que estas comparando... si te muestra un alert con el mensaje "mal" es porque esta MAL NO CREES?

Comment: @JuanOrtiz si no estas declarando esas variables entonces no existen y obviamente te dará un error, podrias mostrar todo tu codigo completo para comprenderte mejor

Comment: si, ya voy, a editar la pregunta y colocaré todo el codigo

Comment: listo, ya editado @LeviArista

Comment: puedes intentar revisando como esta que viene start y end

Comment: no te entendi lo ultimo @LeviArista

Comment: que hagas un `console.log(start) ` y `console.log(end) `